# What the difference between full and not full Scrolls versions?

Tags: scrolls, humble-bundle

I buy [Humble Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/) with bunch of card games includes [Scrolls](http://scrolls.com/). I activate key on my mojang account and now I have full version of Scrolls. But... what the difference between full and demo versions?

I try to google it and search in official wiki but found no information.
Can you tell me what i get? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free version is basically a demo version with a lot of features locked.
These are the features that are unavailable in free version:

**Game Modes**

- Skirmish: Hard
- AI Trials: Medium/Hard (including dailies)
- Ranked Match
- Judgement

**Other Features**

- Crafting
- Store: Preconstructed decks, Avatars
- Black market
- Trading
- Avatar saving
- Shards

[Source](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/Demo)